# Magento's SUPEE-6788 patch not working with Git/Github

Tags: git, security, magento, patch

After I successfully installed the SUPEE-6788 patch on my localhost and pushed the changes to development, I noticed a handful of issues in my dev environment that I did not see on my Localhost.

The first issue I found was that none of my contact form blocks were appearing.

Then I noticed that it wasn't limited to the contact form, it was anywhere that had a form in it (via CMS page).

After digging a bit deeper (exception stack trace), I found out that I was missing a table that didn't exist before called 'permission_block'.

After a bit more digging, I found out that there were many database updates that occurred in the patch which did not run when pushed to development (via upgrade script). Looking at the patch directly, I can see that the upgrade scripts were in fact updated, and that the config files reflected those updates (version number and all). But for some reason, they did not run.

Now I'm left with a bit of a dilemma. I'm not sure what updates happened and what updates have not (in the development environment).

**Are the SUPEE patches Magento releases not meant to be used in conjunction with Git/Github?**

**Do I need to apply the patch individually to each build instead of pushing the build after patching?**

Comment: When pushing anything that includes installer scripts, you must treat it like you were manually upgrading. Flush and turn off the Magento cache and disable the compiler before doing the push. That initial first run after all the patches are in place is VERY important.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did not turn off the cache before the push, but I did flush everything (manually and through Magento's admin) before and after pushing the update to dev. I've never seen an upgrade script fail due to the cache being enabled. It usually runs as soon as I clear the cache. Would not disabling the cache before the push cause this issue? EDIT* I forgot to mention, PART of the upgrade script worked on dev; the password field was set to 100 characters, but the two tables were not created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the SUPEE patches Magento releases not meant to be used in conjunction with Git/Github

There's nothing in the SUPEE patches that would prevent you from using Git/GitHub to manage your repository.

That said -- your question doesn't **quite** make sense, and I think it may be due to a misunderstanding on how those database upgrades are applied.

[Magento Setup Resource scripts](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) allow a module developer to update the database.  Whenever Magento loads **an uncached** HTTP request, it will

1. Examine the version of all declared modules in `app/etc/(code|community|local)`
2. Compare that version to the version stored in the `core_resource` table
3. If a more recent version is installed on the file system, run the appropriate setup resource scripts in `sql/` folder
4. Update `core_resource` to indicate the version installed

Based on your question, it sounds like one of the following happened

1. You uploaded the updated files from source, but never cleared cache in production, and the setup resource scripts never ran
2. You uploaded the updated files, did clear the cache, but something about your production system prevented the scripts from **fully** running.  Since MySQL doesn't have transactional updates for all structure changing commands, it's possible for a setup resource script to not fully run, but still update the `core_resource` table with the same version.

I'd start by comparing the extension version in `core_resource` with the versions on the file system (in `config.xml`)

Also, you can use the `sys:setup:incremental` command that's a part of the [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/) program to manually apply updates without clearing the cache.  This can also help you diagnose which, if any, failures might be causing problems.

Finally, since you have a working development version, as a last resort you can use `mysqldump` to dump the structure of each database, and then compare with a visual diff tool (like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en)) to determine what tables/rows are missing. You'll need to apply a bit of intelligence to this (since dev might also have other un-needed things)

Comment: It's just like you said. Magento thinks it installed the updates even though it did not. I have never used n98-magerun before, but from what I've read, it sounds fantastic. I'm trying it out right now. Also, thanks for the worst case scenario suggestion. Although it's a pain in the butt to do, I might need to perform a diff on the databases.

Comment: Instead of performing a full database dump and a diff, I decided to first check for all install scripts updated from SUPEE-6788. Turns out that there are only two tables created (permission_variable and permission_block). The only other modification is to the admin_user table (password field). I did a comparison between these three tables and applied the difference to the dev database. Everything appears to be in order now, but I still have not been able to pinpoint the root cause. But I'm still digging. I'll do a follow up post once I've figured it out.

Comment: I'm still not 100% certain what the cause of the issue was, but I did the same test I performed yesterday on my dev server and for some reason it worked this time. For now, this is the best answer. If the network engineers respond with a cause, I'll make sure to post it. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Thanks for the info. For some reason it still won't create those two tables for me and I don't have another database to refer to to copy the structure over. n98's incremental run shows no errors, but it appears that my admin sql setup scripts are just flat out not running for no reason whatsoever.